# How to tell Magento that a cache has become invalid?

Tags: magento2, cache

Once a module's configuration in Admin has been changed, **page cache should be invalidated** (I've confirmed it experimentally), but I do not get such warning for this module I've installed.

So, I suppose it's module's responsibility to explicitly mark specific cache type as invalid.

**How can I do it?** If it's by using events, the only "cache" events I've found seem to be fired after caches get cleaned, not after they get invalid.